# Launch a roslaunch file using a push button in Qt (PyQt)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, ros, qtgui

I'm trying to make a GUI for a ROS based program I created. I want to make a push button that will launch a roslaunch file. Is there a command for this? Or maybe an example program would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use [pyqt](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt), you can create a `QPushButton` which when clicked executes the normal roslaunch command. You can set up a function to be called when the button is pressed (using `clicked.connect()`). Inside that function you can use `QProcess` to run an external executable, which in your case will be: 
`roslaunch my_launch_file.launch` or whatever you normally run in the terminal to launch your program.

Here is a simple script that worked for me (ubuntu 14.04, ros indigo):

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class MainLauncher( QWidget ):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.launchButton = QPushButton( "LAUNCH" )
        self.launchButton.clicked.connect( self.onClick )
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.launchButton, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout( mainLayout )

    def onClick(self):
        ROS_PROGRAM = QProcess(self)
        print "Launching..."
        program = 'roslaunch my_launch_file.launch'
        ROS_PROGRAM.start(program)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication( sys.argv )
    mainLauncher = MainLauncher()
    mainLauncher.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can probably switch out PyQt4 for PyQt5 above if needed.